# where to put template button click event

Tags: ember.js

I have button on my **template**(not in component) and need to add click event for it.what is the correct js file to place my click event ?

I search from ember site where it state that component action should put in respective component js action or it will bubbule up to route js . Either It have not mansion or  I couldn't find where to put **template**(not in component) action since there are no place to add the action other than respective route js file.

so is it ok to put my template action in respective route js file ?

I am novice to ember and sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can put action handler(s) inside your route.**

You can handle template event from either corresponding controller or router.

Just put the handling function inside `actions` property inside either place.

The order template look for action is controller first ,router and upper router untile application router.

Comment: Xinyang I got this now  "Assertion Failed: An action named 'toggleButton' was not found in (generated installed-base-detail controller)" It has not searching my action any idea ?

Comment: which means you did not implicitly generate a controller and put you action there. simple fix would be `ember g controller your_controller_name` and put the action handler inside it.

Comment: Try define your action using `filter=(action 'filterByCity')` instead of `filter='filterByCity'` inside your template

Comment: I have included only in respective route file and I have not generated controller for it(I am worrying to generate controller for it since some blog (rumors)are saying that controller going to be deprecated in future version of ember )